# Specifying the App Pool when deploying from Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC4 application. When I publish it to a server I want to be able to tell it to go to a specific app pool, and if it is not present then I want it to be created.
Currently when I deploy it gets put in the wrong app pool and I have to change it manually in IIS. I would like to automate this step.
Has anyone got any hints about how I could do this?
Thanks[image: Deployment Profile]

Comment: Do you use a hosting or is it your server?

Comment: Currently it is on our server, but in future it will be on a hosted environment.

Comment: Even if you can find a way to automate it, you won't have permission on a hosting to configure IIS.

Comment: How do you manage this kind of scenario? The issue is my application needs to run in an application pool with the Managed Pipeline Mode set to Integrated. The DefaultAppPool uses Classic.

Comment: I do everything manually and couldn't find anything related to that on msdn. Personally, never heard of it and think that is not possible yet, but who knows.